# How to make text aligned left/center/right in the same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align some text to left/center/right in the same line. For example, I want to put my phone number on the left, my name in the center, and my email on the right, how do I do that?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Using `\hfill` won't necessarily result in the middle text being centered, as the example below demonstrates. If you want to place the text in such a way that the middle text is really centered, I would suggest using `\parbox`es, as the example shows (I used the `\lipsum[2]` command to generate text to be used only as a reference):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Left longer sample simple text\hfill Center?\hfill Right

\noindent\textbox{Left longer sample text\hfill}\textbox{\hfil Center\hfil}\textbox{\hfill Right}

\noindent\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this construct will be used many times, it would be better to have a command; something along the lines of the `\textline` command whose definition and use are illustrated in the following example (in which I also incorporated **egreg**'s suggestion about `\raggedleft`, `\centering` and `\raggedright`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\textline[4][t]{%
  \par\smallskip\noindent\parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\raggedright\texttt{+}#2}%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\centering#3}%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{#4}}\par\smallskip%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\textline[t]{555\,555\,555}{Some Name}{user@some.site.com}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `\raggedright` in the left box, `\centering` in the middle box and `\raggedleft` in the right box.

Comment: What if any of the parts are wider than `0.333\textwidth`? Then it will be wrapped to fit into the `\textbox`, and everything will not be at the same line anymore.

Comment: This approach mostly works but does not handle empty arguments, longer text, and other edge cases.  [egreg's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55503/28363) cleanly handles these.

Answer (score 39):

The task is accomplished easily with boxes:

```
\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{+999\,555\,999\,555}%
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{Ben Lee User}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{ben.l.user@some.site}}
```

This doesn't check for overlaps, but the chance to getting overlaps is very small.

One macro for it might be

```
\newcommand{\headerline}[3]{%
  \par\medskip\noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}%
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{#2}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{#3}}\par\medskip}
```

to be used as

```
\headerline{+999\,555\,999\,555}{Ben Lee User}{ben.l.user@some.site}
```

### A more efficient (and more obscure) solution

```
\newcommand{\headerline}[3]{%
\par\medskip\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{\rlap{#1}\hfill#2\hfill\llap{\texttt{#3}}}%
\par\medskip}
```

Comment: +1, but wouldn't `\rlap` and `\llap` be easier than the outer `\makebox`'s?

Comment: @MartinScharrer LaTeX syntax versus Plain. :)

Comment: Are `\rlap` and `\llap` considered plain syntax? I didn't know that.

Comment: @MartinScharrer They are slightly dangerous because they *don't* start horizontal mode.

Comment: This works too! But I don't understand what you guys discussed here. What is the difference between LaTeX syntax and plain syntax? And what is horizontal mode?

Comment: @LWZ It's for the *cognoscenti*. :) Don't worry: use what's documented in the manual (`\makebox`). When you'll be an expert, you'll know also when to take a shortcut.

Comment: You can specify left, center, and right with l, c, and r using makebox? That's awesome.

Comment: Instead of `\textwidth` use `\linewidth` in the macros given in this answer. This way the macros also work in other contexts, e.g. in lists items.

Comment: @ComFreek Possibly, but I'm not really sure that this can find usage in such environments.

Comment: @egreg I had one: a beamer slide with an itemize environment where the first item is `\item First $$display$$` and the second item is `\item Second $inline$`. Here, I wanted `$inline$` to appear as centered as `$$display$$`. (I couldn't make it into another display due to space constraints.)

Comment: Awesome answer as always!

Answer (score 29):

```
Left \hfill Center \hfill Right
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count. This assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!) Additionally, you can upvote answers (and questions) that you think are good, by clicking the upward-pointing triangle next to the post.

Comment: @texasAUtiger `\noindent` will probably be necessary and you have to be careful with spurious blank spaces.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it only centers the center part if the left and the right parts are equally long. If the left part is much longer than the right part, or the other way around, the center part will be way off center.

Answer (score 3):

Your question sounds to me like you are doing your CV in LaTeX, or something similar. Yet another solution to achieve neat alignment would be to use a table. Using the `tabularx`package, for example, you can stretch a table to the size `\textwidth` and place each item into its own respective cell.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{float,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X Z Y}
+123 456 789 & Your Name & Your.Name@foobar.com
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This produces a table with three identically-spaced columns, stretching in sum to the size of `\textwidth`. As `Z` is specified, the content of the cells is also centered. Alternatively, `X` would left-align and `Y` right-align. You can use `p{1.5cm}` or so to have a specific column stretch to a predefined size. As long as you use any of `X, Y, Z` together with it, the table will stretch to the width of your text margin.

Comment: Did you mean to write `X Y Z` instead of `Z Z Z`? Separately, since the material isn't meant to "float" anyway, it seems unnecessary to wrap the `tabularx` environment in a `table[H]` environment; prefixing a `\noindent` instruction before `\begin{tabularx}{...}{...}` will do the job.

Comment: You are also missing an `\end{tabularx}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip quinmars. Mico, I just wrap a table environment around tabularx to ensure it is placed exactly where it's meant to be, via the float package.

Comment: ... which sort of makes the whole `table` environment pointless, as long as you're not adding a caption as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Left \hfill Center \hfill Right
```

[image: Result]

Use a \phantom !

```
\phantom{phantom} \hfill \phantom{phantom} \hfill Right
```

[image: Result]

```
Left \hfill \phantom{phantom} \hfill Right
```

[image: Result]