# How to float a figure in LaTeX so it won't change text alignment?

Tags: positioning, titles

I'm trying to create a title page in LaTeX. Here is my code:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}

    \large
    \includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{FIGURE1.jpg}
    \textbf{AUTHOR'S NAME}\hfill

\vfill

    \textbf{TITLE}\\
\vfill

\centering

    ADRESS\\ 
DATE\\

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

The problem is this way `FIGURE1.jpg` is a member of the same line as `AUTHOR'S NAME` is placed just before it and changes the alignment as push `AUTHOR'S NAME` to the right.

I don't want that. I want `FIGURE1.jpg` to be placed at the very left in this line and `AUTHOR'S NAME` to be centered.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make text aligned left/center/right in the same line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55472/how-to-make-text-aligned-left-center-right-in-the-same-line)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like this?  This achieved by putting the two items in a box the width of the line, placing the image first on the line with apparent zero width and the centering the author by adding equal amounts of glue on each side.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}

    \large
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}}\hfill\textbf{AUTHOR'S
    NAME}\hfill} 

\vfill

    \textbf{TITLE}\\
\vfill

\centering

    ADRESS\\ 
DATE\\

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: YES, Andrew. That was exactly what I wanted.
Thank you!