# How to add a copyright notice footer to only the first page of a document?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr

I have a conference paper that requires me to enter a copyright notice to only the first page of the document.

I know that I can use `fancyhdr` to add this. I added the following to my document:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lfoot{This is the copyright notice} %The footer needs to be left aligned
```

I have downloaded the `fancyhdr` style file and added it to the directory. But in the pdf output the footer does not show.

Also after I make it to work it needs to be on the first page only.

**Edit**: Full code below:

```
%% LyX 2.1.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lfoot{This is the copyright notice}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.3
%% 2007/01/11
%% by Michael Shell
%% See:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/
%% for current contact information.
%%
%% This is a skeleton file demonstrating the use of IEEEtran.cls
%% (requires IEEEtran.cls version 1.7 or later) with an IEEE conference paper.
%%
%% Support sites:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
%% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/
%% and
%% http://www.ieee.org/
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% paper title% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{Title here}

\begin{author}
\author{\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, F K\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences, .\\ Email: \{**, **, **i, **\}@dept.comk \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: **@g.com}}}}
\end{author}
\maketitle
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, AA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, FF\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences**.\\ Email: \{**, **, **, **\}@*** \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: ***}}}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Introduction here

\section{Proposed Method}
Method explained here

\section{Conclusion}
Conclusion here

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{SS_bibtex}


% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us a full compilable code. Like this we have to guess around, why this is not working for you. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thank you. Ive added it in the edit above, If this is not what you are looking for please let me know. I exported from LyX and now have to edit in Latex. Below the title tag is my paper, I do not want to add all of it as its still unpublished.

Comment: Thanks. But there is something missing. `\end{document}` and the info, if you are using a titlepage or an abstract. The first page should be simulated (just with bla bla if you want). All the grey stuff can be kicked out and maybe some packages as well (giving us less code to read and treat).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I believe I have added all of it now, and removed anything related to the paper and authors. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` class uses a specific page style for the first page, so it's enough to modify it; loading `fancyhdr` is not the answer: the copy editors won't be happy with it.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  {\footnotesize The copyright belongs to me!\hfill}% <--- Change here
  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}

%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.3
%% 2007/01/11
%% by Michael Shell
%% See:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/
%% for current contact information.
%%
%% This is a skeleton file demonstrating the use of IEEEtran.cls
%% (requires IEEEtran.cls version 1.7 or later) with an IEEE conference paper.
%%
%% Support sites:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
%% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/
%% and
%% http://www.ieee.org/
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% paper title% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{Title here}

\begin{author}
\author{\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, F K\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences, .\\ Email: \{**, **, **i, **\}@dept.comk \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: **@g.com}}}}
\end{author}
\maketitle
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, AA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, FF\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences**.\\ Email: \{**, **, **, **\}@*** \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: ***}}}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Introduction here

\newpage

\section{Proposed Method}
Method explained here

\newpage

\section{Conclusion}
Conclusion here

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{SS_bibtex}


% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I get this error when I added your code to my latex file: ``LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line 510.

! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
\add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
                                                  #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.510 
      
? `` It stops here and does not produce the pdf output

Comment: @ipunished What text did you use for the copyright notice?

Comment: I am required to enter this notice as is: ``978-1-4799-6773-5/14/$31.00 ©2014 IEEE`` now that you mention it, is it because I did not change the copyright symbol to latex compatible?

Comment: @ipunished You should use `\$` for the dollar symbol and `\textcopyright` for `©`.

Comment: In case someone requires multiline text, one can use `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}...\end{minipage}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325013/9075. Note that specifying `conference` or `compsocconf` changes the layout and fonts of the paper. So the linked solution does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright notice hint for LaTeX users
If you are using LaTeX, you can add the IEEE copyright notice like this.

> Step1: Please, add the following package `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`
>
> Step2: Paste the following before “`\begin{document}`”

```
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[c]{}
\fancypagestyle{FirstPage}{
\lfoot{978-1-7281-6455-7/20/\$31.00 \copyright2020 IEEE} 
}
```

> Step3: Add the following immediately after “`\section{Introduction}`” or
> other first section declaration. `\thispagestyle{FirstPage}`

Got this info from this site: https://events.tuni.fi/icl-gnss2020/copyright-notice-hint-for-latex-users/

Comment: This worked for me when I needed to create a personal copy of my paper for ORO. The accepted answer didn't work for me, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200330/88466 possibly as the IEEE have probably updated their template since that answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

My task was to place on the first page (title page) of the IEEE template (\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}):

- copyright sign at the bottom left
- page number centered at the bottom (page number '20' should have been)

Example:
[image]

Here is the solution (hope it helps someone!):

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
...
\pagestyle{plain}
\IEEEpubidadjcol

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\title{...}
\authors{...}    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newcommand\textline[4][t]{%
  \par\smallskip\noindent\parbox[#1]{.4\textwidth}{\raggedright#2}%
  \parbox[#1]{.2\textwidth}{\centering#3}%
  \parbox[#1]{.4\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{#4}}\par\smallskip%
}

\makeatletter

\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
 \textline[t]{979-8-3503-4999-3/23/\$31.00 \copyright 2023 IEEE}{\thepage}{}
  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}


\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{20}

\begin{abstract}
...
```

It helped me: [How to make text aligned left/center/right in the same line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55472/how-to-make-text-aligned-left-center-right-in-the-same-line)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you saw the accepted answer of user egreg?