# How to add the copyright notice at the center of the footer on the first page in IEEEtrans template

Tags: footnotes, ieeetran

I could figure out how to add the copyright notice from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200324/how-to-add-a-copyright-notice-footer-to-only-the-first-page-of-a-document/200330#200330?newreg=783c6168657e42ba87c7ead44f886066), but I can't figure out how to add the copyright notice at the *center* of the first page of a IEEEtran conference class.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  {\footnotesize The copyright belongs to me!\hfill}%
  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}

%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.3
%% 2007/01/11
%% by Michael Shell
%% See:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/
%% for current contact information.
%%
%% This is a skeleton file demonstrating the use of IEEEtran.cls
%% (requires IEEEtran.cls version 1.7 or later) with an IEEE conference paper.
%%
%% Support sites:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
%% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/
%% and
%% http://www.ieee.org/
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% paper title% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{Title here}

\begin{author}
\author{\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, F K\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences, .\\ Email: \{**, **, **i, **\}@dept.comk \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: **@g.com}}}}
\end{author}
\maketitle
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, AA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, FF\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences**.\\ Email: \{**, **, **, **\}@*** \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: ***}}}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Introduction here

\newpage

\section{Proposed Method}
Method explained here

\newpage

\section{Conclusion}
Conclusion here

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{SS_bibtex}


% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE . Have you tried `\centering`? You should provide a MWE to have better answer

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal it is not your concern to place them. The publication office will take care all those stuff for you.

Comment: This is actually a conference. Sorry for not clarifying before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinkering with your setup, one can add another `\hfill` in the beginning in

```
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  {\footnotesize\hfill The copyright belongs to me!\hfill}%   << here
  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}
```

Your example will be:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  {\footnotesize\hfill The copyright belongs to me!\hfill}%
  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% paper title% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{Title here}

\begin{author}
\author{\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, F K\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences, .\\ Email: \{**, **, **i, **\}@dept.comk \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: **@g.com}}}}
\end{author}
\maketitle
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, AA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, FF\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences**.\\ Email: \{**, **, **, **\}@*** \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: ***}}}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Introduction here




% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

[image]

Proper way of doing it is to use

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
```

and use

```
\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00˜\copyright˜2015 IEEE
}
```

An example with this will be

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00˜\copyright˜2015 IEEE
}
\begin{document}
  \title{Title here}

\begin{author}
\author{\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, F K\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences, .\\ Email: \{**, **, **i, **\}@dept.comk \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: **@g.com}}}}
\end{author}
\maketitle
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, AA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, FF\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences**.\\ Email: \{**, **, **, **\}@*** \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: ***}}}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```