# Using IEEE Copyright, not working

Tags: header-footer, copyright

I am trying to put IEEE copyright in my paper. I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr) to make it work, but did not. Then I tried with IEEE latex template but same case. Here is what I have with me right now.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
\graphicspath{{C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\IEEEtran\IEEEtran\}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\title{How Fast U R??}

% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Hodge  }
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Computer Science \\
Mangalore-574199\\
 }
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Aga}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Computer Science  University\\
Mangalore-574199 \\
}}


\IEEEpubid{978-1-4673-9563-2/15/$31.00 ©2015 IEEE}

% make the title area
\maketitle
% abstract goes here



\begin{abstract}
Gene expression data suffer from the curse
\end{abstract}


\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Feature Selection
\end{IEEEkeywords}




\section{Introduction}
% no \IEEEPARstart
 Put your introduction here

\section{Related Works}
This section includes a brief description of the work related to feature selection methods.  
\section{Methodology}
We propose to study the applications of .........



\section{Performance Evaluation}
I will check how fast your are!!.




\section{Conclusion}
Cong!!. Your are reasonably fast.
% references section

\begin{thebibliography}{20}



\bibitem{10} P. Meesad and K. Hengpraprohm, \emph{Combination of KNN-based feature selection and KNN-based missing-value imputation of microarray data}, 3rd Int. Conf. Innov. Comput. Inf. Control. ICICIC’08, no. 1, pp. 3–6, 2008.



\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What do you mean by "put IEEE copyright in my paper"? The question you've linked deals with headers and footers, is there a certain part of the paper you want to put in the header and footer?

Comment: copyright `978-1-4673-9563-2/15/$31.00 ©2015 IEEE` as a footer

Comment: Discussion of a very similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279769/9075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the lines that worked for me. Adding the below lines before `/begin{document}`

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-4673-9563-2/15/\$31.00~
\copyright~2015 IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{}}
```

At the same time removed this line.

```
\IEEEpubid{978-1-4673-9563-2/15/$31.00 ©2015 IEEE}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the answer directly from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200324/how-to-add-a-copyright-notice-footer-to-only-the-first-page-of-a-document), I suggest you add the following to your preamble (that is, before `\begin{document}`):

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  {\hfill \footnotesize 978-1-4673-9563-2/15/\$31.00 \copyright 2015 IEEE\hfill}
}
\makeatother
```

Compiling it all together with the exact code you have above should get you what you want.

Comment: Please add the missing `\makeatother` ;-)

Comment: Thanks your code is working, but leaving copyright at  the middle