# IEEEtran: how to add copyright footer at the center of bottom with multiple lines

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, ieeetran

I have a journal paper that requires me to enter the copyright footer. The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200324/how-to-add-a-copyright-notice-footer-to-only-the-first-page-of-a-document) partially solved my problem.

However, the content of the footer is

> `Copyright~\copyright~2017 IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. However, permission to use this material for any other purposes must be obtained from the IEEE by sending a request to pubs-permissions@ieee.org.`

which is too long to fit in one line. I tried to use line break `\\` or `\newline`, it doesn't work. What is the correct method to break the copyright footer into multiple lines in IEEEtran? Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to add that if you are just submitting to the journal and doing nothing else. They will add it for you.

Comment: I was provided a checklist for final submission, in which it requires me to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured it out. The way to do is to use a minipage for the copyright content. One example is as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}
  \def\@evenfoot{}
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{
  {\footnotesize
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  Copyright~\copyright~2017 IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. However, permission to use this  \\ 
  material for any other purposes must be obtained from the IEEE by sending a request to pubs-permissions@ieee.org.
  \end{minipage}
  }
}
```