# Putting IEEE copyright on a document title page

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

I want to upload an accepted IEEE paper to arxiv, hence I have to manually insert the Copyright notice on the title page. I have already found some questions (e.g., [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279131/44467), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349112/44467) ) on how to put the IEEE copyright notice on a paper. While it is possible to put a copyright notice on the bottom of the title page with the linked answers, the heading is also miraculously changed from the “journal name” to “author names: paper title” (the second instead of the first argument of `\markboth`).

Example Code which produces the describe results:

```
%!TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[twoside]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
% uncomment the following part to see a changing header
%\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
%  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
%  \def\@evenfoot{}%
%}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering \scriptsize
  Copyright~\copyright~20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or future media, including\\reprinting/republishing this material for advertising or promotional purposes, creating new collective works, for resale or redistribution to servers or lists, or reuse of any copyrighted component of this work in other works by sending a request to pubs-permissions@ieee.org.
  \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\markboth{IEEE Transactions}%
{An Author: A Title} 
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the question, I had the idea to just add an `\@oddhead` where the custom `\@oddfoot` is set. It works, but it is not the nicest solution since it requires one to manual copy the first argument of `\markboth`.

Edit: Looking up the definition of `IEEEtran.cls`, it is easy to just copy the definion of `\@oddhead` to avoid the mentioned manual copy of the argument of `\markboth`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\@IEEEheaderstyle\leftmark\hfil\thepage}\relax
  \def\@evenhead{\@IEEEheaderstyle\thepage\hfil\leftmark\hbox{}}\relax
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering \scriptsize
  Copyright~\copyright~20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or future media, including\\reprinting/republishing this material for advertising or promotional purposes, creating new collective works, for resale or redistribution to servers or lists, or reuse of any copyrighted component of this work in other works by sending a request to pubs-permissions@ieee.org.
  \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: For me, this adds a strange page numbering on the title page top right. Removing everything other than `oddfoot` worked for me.