# How to put a footer on all pages of IEEEtrans.cls?

Tags: ieeetran, footer

My problem is that this solution [1] adds a footer **only to the title page** of an IEEEtrans paper.
I want to add it to **all pages**.

Can anyone help?

Ref.
[1] [IEEEtran: how to add copyright footer at the center of bottom with multiple lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349112/ieeetran-how-to-add-copyright-footer-at-the-center-of-bottom-with-multiple-line)

Comment: The footer you mean on the bottom center not at each column? Worth noting IEEEtran's copyright footnote is achieved by reducing the title page content length.

Comment: The first step is to get permission from IEEE to change their page geometry and \pagestyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the footnote of the first page and also the style of the following pages.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}    

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY for dummy text ! 

%********************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200330/161015
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{% works only for the first page
    \def\@oddfoot{\customfootnote}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\customfootnote}{\footnotesize 978-1-7381-4484-9/23/\$31.00 \copyright2023 IEEE \hfill}% define /edit here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{GlobalFootnote}{%
    \lfoot{\customfootnote} 
}
\pagestyle{GlobalFootnote} % style for following pages

%*********************

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Title here}
    
    \begin{author}
        \author{\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Simon Dispa\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, F K\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  R P\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and S H\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences, .\\ Email: \{**, **, **i, **\}@dept.comk \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: **@gmail.com}}}}
    \end{author}

    \maketitle
    
    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{FK\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, AA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, FF\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},  Ri\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and Sd\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Computing, Engineering and Information Sciences**.\\ Email: \{**, **, **, **\}@*** \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science and Engineering, ***\\ Email: ***}}}
    
    \begin{abstract}
    \kant[1]
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \kant[2-4]
    
    \section{Proposed Method}
    \kant[5-8]
    
    \section{Conclusion}
    \kant[9-12] 

\end{document}
```