# Left align, center align and right align a line of three parts respectively

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a document like this

```
\textbf{Company Name}, \textit{Position} \hfill{City, State} \hfill Jan 2018--May 2018
\begin{itemize}
    \item Some bullet point
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Longer Company Name}, \textit{Position} \hfill{City, State} \hfill Jan 2018--May 2018
```

[image]

I want the `City, State` part to be center aligned (or consistently aligned across different entries if not centered). Maybe`tabular` could work, but I don't know how to put `itemize` inside the `tabular` and allow it to span the entire line.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This question should help: [How to make text aligned left/center/right in the same line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55472/579).  (Potential duplicate.)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `l`eft, `c`entre and `r` component in appropriately-aligned `\makebox`es of zero width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\textbf{Company Name}, \textit{Position} \hfill{City, State} \hfill Jan 2018--May 2018

\begin{itemize}
  \item Some bullet point
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Longer Company Name}, \textit{Position} \hfill{City, State} \hfill Jan 2018--May 2018

\noindent\hrulefill

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{Company Name}, \textit{Position}}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][c]{City, State}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{Jan 2018--May 2018}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Some bullet point
\end{itemize}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{Longer Company Name}, \textit{Position}}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][c]{City, State}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{Jan 2018--May 2018}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With use of packages `tabularx` and `enumitem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}M c 
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}M @{}}
\textbf{Company Name}, \textit{Position} 
 \begin{tabitem}
    \item Some bullet point
\end{tabitem}           
        & City, State   & Jan 2018--May 2018    \\
\textbf{Longer Company Name}, \textit{Position} 
        & City, State   & Jan 2018--May 2018
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```