# How to center a part of a text but not the text left or right from it - with a rule

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Actually I already found an answer to the [center text left/middle/right-problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55472/how-to-make-text-aligned-left-center-right-in-the-same-line/593633#593633):

The big question is how to add a filling rule  between the text parts. I tried the following, facing the problem that the rule overlaps with the text:

```
\noindent \Large \makebox[0pt][l]{Number}%
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\hrulefill Title \hrulefill}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{}
```

How to fix it properly ?

Comment: Does the title actually need to be centred? I would suggest `\noindent \Large\parbox{.5\textwidth}{Number~\hrulefill}\parbox{.5\textwidth}{Title~\hrulefill}\par`

Comment: Yea thank you for your suggestion. However centered text is much more appealing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

### Compute the alignment explicitly

```tex
{\Large \setbox0=\hbox{Title}
 \setbox1=\hbox{Number}
 \dimen0=\hsize \advance\dimen0 by-\wd0
 \divide\dimen0 by 2
 \dimen1=\dimen0 \advance\dimen1 by-\wd1
 \hbox to\hsize{\box1\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimen1 plus1fil
  \box0\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimen0plus 1fil}}
```

In order to overcome rounding errors, the leaders are made stretchable by adding `plus 1fil`.

### Employ TeX's typesetting algorithm (preferred)

Give the first rulefill (between `Number` and `Title`) a minimum width of zero, plus 1fill of stretchability. But let the second rulefill (after `Title`) be at least as wide as the text `Number`, again plus 1fill of stretchability. Then TeX uses the same amount of stretchability for both rulefills, but adds the minimum width to the second rulefill, making it wider by the width of `Number`, exactly what is desired.

```tex
\hbox to\hsize{\Large
 \setbox0=\hbox{Number}\dimen0=\wd0
 \box0 \leaders\hrule\hfill
 Title\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimen0 plus 1fill}
```